# Create internal messaging system, I start from scratch or I rely on a bundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have to implement a feature in my application page in the frontend of the site where users can submit requests, with different data name, phone number, email, description request ..

and this request is to be sent by mail and be displayed in the backend, where you can reply to the message, and then send the answer via email.

I ask you some advice based on your experience, I begin to do everything from scratch,

or can I rely on a bundle type FOSMessageBundle and maybe extend the functionality I need?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely give the FOSMessageBundle a try. The FOS bundles are very well maintained and documented, so it should be a great starting point!